# OpenGL 3.3 texture mapping triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, texture-mapping, opengl-3

I have had little luck simply texturing a triangle in Opengl 3.3 (core) over the last few days. I can successfully render the vertices and colors, but texturing seems to be problematic. My current task/goal is vertices and texture coordinates only (no colors).

Since I create the test texture by hand, it should show up as a 16x16 white/red checkered triangle.

Strange behavior: If I use GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, it's all WHITE. If I use GL_REPEAT, it comes out pink (white + red)...

vertex shader:

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
out vec2 tex;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix, projMatrix;
void main()
{
  gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(vertPos,1.0);
  tex = texCoord;
};
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330
out vec4 Color;
in vec2 tex;
uniform sampler2D texsampler;
void main() {
  Color = texture(texsampler, tex);
};
```

state initialization code (these are in order as shown):

```
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
  //glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,1);

  glFrontFace(GL_CW);  // clockwise oriented polys are front faces
  glCullFace(GL_BACK); // cull out the inner polygons... Set Culling property appropriately

  glLineWidth(1.0f); // for any wireframe

  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); // color 1.0f is fully opaque, 0.0f is transparent

  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
  glDepthRange(0,1); // default

  glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

  glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f); // set clear color to black

  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL); // filled polys
```

texture initialization:

```
  glGenTextures(1,&texid1);
  glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid1);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    uint32 buf[16*16];
    uint32 x;
    for (x=0;x<16*16;) {
      buf[x++] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
      buf[x++] = 0xFFFF0000;
    }

    glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8 , 16, 16, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)buf);

  glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

shader initialization:

```
  shader1 = new_gl_shader_program(vert_src,frag_src);
  if (shader1) {
    if (link_gl_shader_program(shader1)) {

      projMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader1, "projMatrix");
      viewMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader1, "viewMatrix");

      sampler2dLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader1, "texsampler");

      glBindFragDataLocation( shader1, 0, "Color" ); // ADDED.

    }
    else {
      print("LINK ERROR: %s\n",get_gl_shader_msg());
      delete_gl_shader_program(shader1);
      shader1 = 0;
    }
  }
  else
    print("COMPILE/MISC ERROR: %s\n",get_gl_shader_msg());

  if (!shader1)
    return;
```

buffer data initialization:

```
typedef struct MESH_VERT_3D {
  float x,y,z;
  float u,v;
}MESH_VERT_3D;

MESH_VERT_3D meshbuf[3]; // total of 15 floats

    meshbuf[0].x = 0.0f;
    meshbuf[0].y = 0.0f;
    meshbuf[0].z = 0.0f;

    meshbuf[1].x = 1.0f;
    meshbuf[1].y = 0.0f;
    meshbuf[1].z = 0.0f;

    meshbuf[2].x = 1.0f;
    meshbuf[2].y = 0.0f;
    meshbuf[2].z = 1.0f;

    meshbuf[0].u = 0.0f;
    meshbuf[0].v = 1.0f;
    meshbuf[1].u = 1.0f;
    meshbuf[1].v = 1.0f;
    meshbuf[2].u = 1.0f;
    meshbuf[2].v = 0.0f;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboid);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboid);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(meshbuf), meshbuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoHandle);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboid);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*5, null);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,sizeof(float)*5, (void*)(sizeof(float)*3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

render:

```
  gls_begin_3d(&glscene);
  use_gl_shader_program(shader1);

  glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatrixLoc,  1, GL_FALSE, gls_get_projection_matrix());
  glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixLoc,  1, GL_FALSE, gls_get_modelview_matrix());

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid1);
  glUniform1i(sampler2dLoc, 0);

  glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );

  glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  use_gl_shader_program(0);
  gls_end_3d(&glscene);
```

Comment: Its come up no error.

Comment: Added a call to glGetError() within the rendering loop.. It is spewing out 0x0 (no error).

Comment: In hindsight, this is the most thorough question and set of answers on the matter of fundamental Opengl 3.3+ texture mapping with glsl on stackoverflow and the web. Something like this would have helped me days ago to get up and running. I hope it helps others out there, so they aren't discouraged like I was before! Granted, 95% can be tracked down on web (via google, etc), but that last bit (5%) of helpful info really helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

You should bind your fragment shader output variable `Color` to a fragment data location:

```
glBindFragDataLocation( shader1, 0, "Color" );
```

Otherwise OpenGL does not know where the results of your shader program are located.

**Issue 2:**

You create a second buffer object for your texture coordinates: `glGenBuffers(1, &tboid);` However, everything should be put into a single VBO.

**Issue 3:**

You pass `null` to `glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,sizeof(float)*5, null);` However, the beginning of texture coordinates is not 0. It is `sizeof(float)*3`.

**Issue 4:**

In the vertex shader, you have `out vec2 texCoordOut;`. However, in the fragment shader, you use
`in vec2 tex;`. The names should match.

Comment: I updated the question a little better. I will look into your suggestion.

Comment: Try debugging it. Instead of ``Color = texture(texsampler, tex);`` write ``Color = vec4(tex.x, tex.y, 0.0, 0.0);`` and tell us what you see.

Comment: Okay, I added that to the shader initialization section (on my side) below "sampler2dLoc = ...". It did not seem to make a difference. That suggestion still makes a lot of sense though. Hmm.

Comment: If it makes no difference then the problem is not in texturing.

Comment: Okay! I added Color = vec4(tex.x, tex.y, 0.0, 0.0); to the fragment shader like you suggested and now nothing comes up! It is blank (black?)!

Comment: Ok. Let's go ahead and put ``vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5 )`` there. Do you see a red image? If so, your ``tex`` values are wrong.

Comment: Yes. Per your suggestion it is now Red. From what you can see, do they look wrong ?! They look correct to me..

Comment: From my point of view they are all 0's. Btw, I cannot find where you assign values to them.

Comment: Yeah they do seem to be acting as all 0's. They are assigned under the buffer data initialization section above. texbuf[].

Comment: Why do you use ``tboid`` for them? You have to put both vertices and texture coordinates in a single VBO. This is the bug number 2.

Comment: Great question. I originally had my data interleaved, but broke them apart when I was having problems a few days ago. Does it matter? I can change it back to one VBO and test.

Comment: Yes, put them in 1 VBO, please.

Comment: Why do you pass ``null`` here ``glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,sizeof(float)*5, null);``? The beginning of texture coordinates is ``sizeof(float)*3`` - we have to bypass ``x``, ``y``, and ``z``.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. Source updated. However, it still is all white :/

Comment: @SergeyK.: neither of the two issues you mention in this answer is a real bug. The spec guarantees that, if a fragment shader has only one output, it is assigned color number 0. Using separate VBOs for the attribute arrays isn't wrong (although one could argue about efficency)

Comment: Thank for your assistance, Sergey. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @CoderX: so much work and the correct (and most full) answer is not accepted.

Comment: @derhass: There are 4 issues.

Comment: @SergeyK.: the time I read it, there weren't. Bug 3 was just a consequence of his changes due to your pseudobug 2.

Comment: @derhass: I renamed them to ``Issues`` instead of bugs.

Comment: @SergeyK.: "Issue" 1 is still completely wrong and 2 doubtful at least.

Comment: @derhass: could you, please, tell the spec paragraph number, where it guarantees the default outputs?

Comment: @SergeyK.: e.g in 3.3core, section 3.9 "Shader Outputs" (just after `BindFragDataLocation` is described): "When a program is linked, any varying out variables **without a binding specified** either through BindFragDataLocationIndexed or `BindFragDataLocation`,
or explicitly set within the shader text will automatically be bound to fragment colors and indices by the GL. All such assignments will use color indices of **zero**."

Comment: @derhass:: Ahhh! I see now. You are speaking about OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile and you are right. However, this functionality is missing in OpenGL 4.4 Core Profile http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.withchanges.pdf So your remark that my issue 1 is wrong is actually a bad practice and return to a deprecated behavior.

Comment: @SergeyK.: Actually, you were right about this all the time. I could have sworn that there was such a guarantee, but I can't find it in the spec. The paragraph I quoted earlier just guarantees the color _index_ is 0, the color _number_ is still arbitrary. The 4.4 spec didn't change any of this behavior, the wording is just more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the vertex shader, you have

```
out vec2 texCoordOut;
```

but in the fragment shader, you use

```
in vec2 tex;
```

This is not going to work, since you are required to use the same name so the GL can match it up.

Comment: @CoderX: LoL, there were 3 bugs before that :)